# Find the density of the random variable X(t)(Kolmogorov Forward equation)

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Let $V(x) = x^2 / 2+ W(x)$ where $W(x)$ is a smooth function with compact support. Let $f$ denote the probability density. $f(x) = \frac{e^{-V(x)}}{\int e^{-V(x)}dx}$. 
Consider the stochastic differential equation : 
$dx(t) = dB(t) - V'(B(t))dt$ with $X(0) = x_0$

where $x_0$ is a random variable independent of $B(s)$ with density $f(x)$.

Find the density of the random variable $X(t)$.

I am pretty sure this looks like an application of Kolmogorov forward equation. But the right hand terms are not expressed in terms of $X(t)$ so I was wondering, if someone can show me how it is done as I have never seen an example using Kolmogorov forward equation before. (Thanks in advance)

Comment: Obviously, $V'(B(t))$ should read $V'(x(t))$.

Comment: I double checked but it is $V'(B(t))$. It might be a typo however.But even in this case ($V'(x(t))$), I was wondering how do you proceed finding the density? I have only seen the equation being mentioned for finding the density, but I would appreciate if I could see a worked out example such as the one I posted.